# AWS Client VPN Linux client has disappeared?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

I downloaded the AWS Client VPN Linux client earlier this year. But after an OS re-install the download seems to have been removed from the AWS website?

Comment: AWS now recommends OpenVPN. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/ubuntu.html

Comment: Ah I cannot use that because my system administrator has Client VPN endpoint has been configured to use SAML-based federated authentication,

Comment: https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/using-saml-for-user-authentication-with-onelogin-as-the-identity-provider/

Comment: but the aws doc you linked says I cannot "Important
If the Client VPN endpoint has been configured to use SAML-based federated authentication, you cannot use the Ubuntu-based VPN client to connect to a Client VPN endpoint."

Comment: You should contact your systems administrator for assistance/guidance, then.